# AnkhSVN Merge Wizard does nothing on Finish for "Reintegrate a branch"

Tags: ankhsvn

Trying to do a merge from a branch back into the trunk.  Both projects are "clean."

When I click the final "Finish" button in the Merge Wizard it churns for a bit (SVN window "Merging - please wait...") and then it goes back to the Merge Wizard without anything in the underlying Pending changes window.  I can click finish over and over and see no change.

I was expecting the changes from my branch to now be updates to my trunk - or at least SOMETHING to happen, but I can't find anything that has happened.

Is there somewhere else to look for an error/status update that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error listed in your "answer" means that you should merge 7-41 from trunk to the branch before reintegrating. Your branch should contain all changes from trunk before you can reintegrate it

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the problem was that I never correctly branched in the first place (about a year ago... not sure now how it went down).

I was able to get an error message by attempting the reintegration operation with TortisSVN in windows.  The error is:

```
Command: Reintegrate merge 
Error: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 7 through 270 were previously merged   
Error: from   
Error: https://.../trunk   
Error: to the reintegrate source, but this is not the case:  
Error:   .../branches/branchProject  
Error:     Missing ranges: .../trunk:7-41  
Finished!:
```

So I'll probably copy the code and do a checkin and not depend on correct branch/merge history to exist for this branch

Comment: This is not an answer, you can edit the question to add more information about your question instead.